# Template class error in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I understand this has been asked million times but still I just couldn't found the solution.

I am using OSX 10.8, boost 1.50, xcode 4.5.1.

- I installed boost using macports.
- created an empty xcode project. My main.cpp contains the following code

```
    #include "boost/container/deque.hpp"
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        boost::container::deque d(12, 5.5f);
        return 0;
    }
```

- updated 'header search path' to point to '/opt/local/include'
- updated 'library search path' to point to '/opt/local/lib'
- tried changing 'c++ language dialect', 'c++ standard library' and other settings with no success at all.

when I build the project, I get error related to semantic issue in allocator_traits.hpp and deque.hpp and I have no idea why. I am afraid as I start using more boost libraries more errors will pop up.

deque.hpp (line 482 and 483) 
base specifier must be a class name (ptr_alloc_t and allocator_type)

what else do I need to do to configure boost. why using boost is so complicated?

Comment: `boost::container::deque<float> d(12, 5.5f);` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Try `#include <boost/container/deque.hpp>`

Answer (score 2):

`boost::container::deque` is a template class and you must specify which type do you use. In your case this is `float`:

```
boost::container::deque<float> d(12, 5.5f);
```

You can read more about templates [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html)

Comment: Interesting. So the example I was following was wrong. weird. I lost the link else I would have mentioned it here to get more feedback.   
Also, this example doesn't work with c++11 but works with c++98. Is it because this library is not yet fully compatible with modern c++11 compiler?
(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/deque.html)